# Larger preview of image in cms admin

Tags: image, silverstripe

I have a `ModelAdmin` which stores images among other things. I can do thumbnails up to a certain size and download them but is there a way to display a larger version of the image while in the CMS admin?

I think if I used the `UploadField.ss` template and added some custom code in there to display it, it could work however it would then be displayed through the CMS. Does SilverStripe provide an easy way to do this?

Comment: Would you like to display a larger preview in the gridfield or in the upload filed?

Comment: @csy_dot_io that would be ok but would prefer it in the detail view which is just a standard layout using getCMSFields

Comment: Yeah - possibly best to add a template for your custom field, then add the image to your template and style it as required

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the height and width of the upload field preview like that

```
UploadField::create('Image', 'Bild')
  ->setPreviewMaxWidth(120)
  ->setPreviewMaxHeight(120)
  ->addExtraClass('big-preview');
```

But the container size seems hardcoded in css so you need to change that too

```
.big-preview .ss-uploadfield .ss-uploadfield-item .ss-uploadfield-item-preview {
  height: 120px;
  line-height: 120px;
  width: 120px;
}

.big-preview .ss-uploadfield .ss-uploadfield-item .ss-uploadfield-item-info {
  margin-left: 135px;
}
```

I don't know if that's the best way to do it, cause it seems a little bit hacky, but it works.